# How to disable access url without bowser?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

How to block/disable if user access my website without browser?
Because I want to make that user only can access my website used browser.
in this case, I'm using `Laravel` and `Vue js`.

My issues:

1. in my purchase page, I want user only post data use ajax, user can't post using postman and etc.

Maybe any suggestions?

Comment: You could try to use a captcha to make it more difficult. But why is it a big problem where the request comes from, as long as it's valid? If you have user authentication in place then you probably don't need captcha in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

**Its not possible.**

There are many solutions to identify requests those are not from browsers (with Javascript etc.) but there is no garantuee.

Also its unclear if a selenium browser counts as as a browser for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Depending on how you're serving the app, you may be able to deny requests based on known-bot user agents, but that's just a deterrent. The client has complete control over the `User-Agent` header, and can quite easily mimic a browser.